# Is it possible to retrieve files that git deleted that were not commited?

Tags: git

I created a brand new git repo that I wanted to sync to one already on a remote. Unfortunately, I added some new files to this new local repo before I added the remote as origin, and I forgot to commit these new files before I pulled. Therefore there was no initial commit locally. As a result those new files were deleted when I pulled. Is there anyway to get them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you made a `git add`, then git has already created `blob` objects for these files, but not connected them to the `commit` DAG. You can look for unconnected objects using the `git fsck` command, which should give you a list of `blob` and `tree` objects.

The files you are looking for are inside `blob`s, whose contents can be dumped using `git cat-file` (IIRC, cannot test right now). The `git fsck` command will not show `blob`s referenced by `tree`s, because these are not unreferenced, so if you cannot find the files you are looking for, you might have to look at some of the `tree` objects to find more `blob`s.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't commit the new files, then looking for them in the log won't help.

What remains is some kind of [data recovery software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_recovery_software), like [Recuva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recuva).

Answer (score 0):

Using `git log`, locate your last commit that you want to roll back to, and use

`git checkout $COMMIT_ID$`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not valid in your case but if you happened to be using eclipse and the files that was deleted was located inside one of your projects, then you can always do a "Restore from Local History..." in eclipse. This has saved me a few times.

Comment: would this be an action using Maven?